# Enumerate logon sessions remotely

Tags: c, winapi, citrix

I want to **enumerate logon sessions on a remote host** (citrix terminal server). What I found so far is `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions() / LsaGetLogonSessionData()`, but you can't call it remotely. 
I read some docs about RPC, but if I understood it right, you need an extra application on the remote host that executes your functions (that's something I want to avoid).
Is there a way to implement such a thing? Maybe with the remote desktop api?

Another solution I found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Win32_LogonSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it is possible to call WMI from a remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

Other options include the WTS APIs: [WTSEnumerateSessionsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee621014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you want to be Citrix specific you can also use the [XenApp PowerShell SDK](http://community.citrix.com/display/xa/XenApp+6.5+Powershell+SDK).